# Setting the YouTube playback speed from within the URL

Tags: youtube, url

I'd like to adjust the YouTube playback speed from within the video's URL.
I haven't tried anything so far, because I'm unclear about the permitted options.

Is this possible? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to change the playback speed by URL arguments. The best you can do is to use extensions which adds extra buttons or ability to bind keyboard shortcuts to speed acceleration/deceleration. For example **[Video Speed Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk)**

If this is HTML related you should check **[YouTube Player iFrame API Playback Rate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_rate)**

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  player.setPlaybackRate(4); // 4x speed
  event.target.playVideo();
}
```

Full code example **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/e11oy0eu/)**.